# How to specify a port when creating a WFS service?

Tags: wfs, arccatalog

This is a [arcgis forum posting](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/56090-How-to-specify-a-port-when-creating-a-WFS-service?p=192455#post192455) simplified.  When setting up a service using ArcCatalog 9.3.1 the URL port number is not included in the WFS GetCapabilities response.  Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a server to "GIS Servers" be sure to include the port information.  For example:

- double-click "Add ArcGIS Server" and select "Manage GIS Services".
- In the "Server URL" provide http://www.myserver.com:5000/arcgis/services.
- You may need to reboot the PC for the changes to take affect.